# Trying to get the uptime of a serviced service, I have the state up/down

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to get the uptime i.e. how long a service has been running. I managed to get the service up/down status. I did some mappings in the stat panel for 0 and 1.

This is my query

```
node_systemd_unit_state{instance="x.x.x.x:9100", name="service01.service", state="active"}
```

So that does work but I can't figure out how to get the uptime of a service.

Not the uptime of the machine but the service.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [process-exporter](https://github.com/ncabatoff/process-exporter) for this. In this case, the metric you're searching for is the following:

```
# HELP namedprocess_namegroup_oldest_start_time_seconds start time in seconds since 1970/01/01 of oldest process in group
# TYPE namedprocess_namegroup_oldest_start_time_seconds gauge
namedprocess_namegroup_oldest_start_time_seconds{groupname="xxxxx"} 1.619627766e+09
```